# Start Date Filter/Set with Most Recent Saturday and Go Back 28 Days

Tags: tableau-api, date-range, relative-date

I have a tableau dashboard where I would want to add a button which, when clicked, filters the data to the most recent 28 day period ending on the last Saturday. So if today is Tuesday 8/11, clicking the button would start at Saturday, Aug 8th and go back 28 days.

Comment: Is your problem still unsolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a set on your date field say `New_date` like this

[image]

Please do tell if this works.  In my opinion this should

Comment: Does this start at most recent saturday?

Comment: Yes @user13203033, the formula has been written like that.  Check if it works!

Comment: IT WORKS! however how to I adjust the second part, it ends at 10/2  @ 0000 but I want it to end at 10/3 @ 1159

Comment: One last question, how would I adjust this to do the 28 day period before the current 28 day period, so it would end where the one you provided starts.

Comment: It would have been easier if you would have provided some sample data to work upon.